# Spring JPA with collection count

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a project where I have given an entity **`Customer`** which has a collection of **`Order`** entities, hence a OneToMany relation between **`Customer`** and **`Order`**. Assuming that I want to select a subset of the **`Customer`** collection with the respective number of **`Order`** entities (in SQL known as `COUNT`): Isn't there already a default implementation for the query methods provided by Spring Data JPA to avoid writing a custom query with JPQL that fetches the number of orders by customer in one SQL-query instead of *n+1* queries where *n* is the number of customers? Or some kind of annotation that can be added in  **`Customer`** on some kind of transient field such as `long orderCount`?

Answer (score 2):

If you name the repository interface methods correctly, Spring Data JPA will automagically create the appropriate COUNT SQL.  As an example, the two repository methods below will count the number of orders by customer ID or customer last name

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order,Long> {
  Long countByCustomerId(Long id);
  Long countByCustomerLastName(String lastName);
}
```

Please peruse the code in the link below for full context

https://github.com/juttayaya/stackoverflow/tree/master/CustomerOrder

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort to setup this demo git repo. Unfortunately this is not the answer I was looking for. To get a better idea what I mean in the context of your example: You could implement an additional testcase to get all customers and for each customer you want to know the number of orders. Therefore, you have got `customerRepository.findAll()` in a loop (with `customer` as iteration variable and then you access e.g. `customer.getOrders().size()` which results in _n+1_ queries. That is why I talked about some kind of transient field `long orderCount` in **`Customer`**.

Comment: One alternative is change `customer.getOrders()` to `FetchType.LAZY` and invoke `orderRepository.countByCustomerId()` . Now the _n+1_ is just for the COUNT of the orders, which is not as onerous.

Comment: Another alternative is to keep the `FetchType.EAGER` for `customer.getOrders()` and use the Hibernate-specific annotation `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)` . This will get a customer and all the orders in one SQL query via LEFT OUTER JOIN, bypassing the _n+1_ issue entirely.